# Google play game services, waiting room after invite friends

Tags: google-plus, google-play-games

I want to show in my app the waiting acitivity... I see it in the google i/o video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duIV7mYZP6s) at 3:15 minutes at the center of the three screens.. Who can help me?

Thanks John

Answer (score 0):

This is provided for in the API via Starting an Activity for Result,  and is explained here [Google Play Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/multiplayer#handling_invitations)

Scroll down to the area title "Optional: Adding a waiting room UI"

launch the built-in waiting room UI, use the Intent returned by GamesClient.getRealTimeWaitingRoomIntent().

You can launch the waiting room UI in the RoomUpdateListener.onRoomConnected and the RoomUpdateListener.onJoinedRoom callbacks.

```
// arbitrary request code for the waiting room UI.
// This can be any integer that's unique in your Activity.
final static int RC_WAITING_ROOM = 10002;

@Override
public void onJoinedRoom(int statusCode, Room room) 
{
    if (statusCode != GamesClient.STATUS_OK) 
    {
       // display error
       return;  
    }

    // get waiting room intent
    Intent i = getGamesClient().getRealTimeWaitingRoomIntent(room, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
}

@Override
public void onRoomCreated(int statusCode, Room room) 
{
    if (statusCode != GamesClient.STATUS_OK) 
    {
        // display error
        return;
    }

    // get waiting room intent
    Intent i = getGamesClient().getRealTimeWaitingRoomIntent(room, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
}
```

Comment: it isn't that i want... can you explane any example?

Comment: Have you tried the demo projects from Google (ButtonClicker, etc..)?

Answer (score 0):

Show the default waiting room when `onRoomCreated` and `onRoomJoined` and dismiss the waiting room in `onRoomConnected`

```
private void showWaitingRoom(Room room) {
    final int MIN_PLAYERS = 1;
    Intent i = getGamesClient().getRealTimeWaitingRoomIntent(room, MIN_PLAYERS);
    startActivityForResult(i, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
}

private void dismissWaitingRoom() {
    finishActivity(RC_WAITING_ROOM);
}
```